# How to troubleshoot workstation not auto-updating chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome Extension that is deployed via GPO to corporate windows machines and is hosted outside the chrome store. It's deployed firmwide to a few dozen different companies, each of which have a custom .crx file with a different auto-update URL to allow them to manage when they get new versions. Normally everything works fine but at one company they have some workstations that auto-update fine and some workstations that do not. The fact that some workstations auto-update fine seems to indicate that the problem isn't with the .crx or the update xml file.

I ran chrome on a problematic workstation with `--enable-logging` turned on to get a debug log of the auto-update behavior, using this command line:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --vmodule=extension_updater=2 --enable-logging --extensions-update-frequency=30`

Here's the output of the extension_updater module from `chrome_debug.log`. Notably it does NOT include my extension's key (which starts `dcpd...`), although above these extension_updater.cc lines there were many lines from my extension logging various startup information, indicating it was definitely installed. However, when I take this log myself on a machine where auto-update does work there's also nothing logged for my extension unless there's a new version available. Unfortunately it seems there's no debug logging that says 'no updates available for extension XXX'.

```
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(445)] Starting update check 0
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension ahfgeienlihckogmohjhadlkjgocpleb is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension dnhpdliibojhegemfjheidglijccjfmc is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension eemcgdkfndhakfknompkggombfjjjeno is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension ennkphjdgehloodpbhlhldgbnhmacadg is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension gfdkimpbcpahaombhbimeihdjnejgicl is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension kmendfapggjehodndflmmgagdbamhnfd is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension mfehgcgbbipciphmccgaenjidiccnmng is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension mgndgikekgjfcpckkfioiadnlibdjbkf is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension neajdppkdcdipfabeoofebfddakdcjhd is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension nkeimhogjdpnpccoofpliimaahmaaome is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140321:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension pafkbggdmjlpgkdkcbjmhmfcdpncadgh is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140322:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(765)] Finished update check 0
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(445)] Starting update check 1
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension ahfgeienlihckogmohjhadlkjgocpleb is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension dnhpdliibojhegemfjheidglijccjfmc is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension eemcgdkfndhakfknompkggombfjjjeno is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension ennkphjdgehloodpbhlhldgbnhmacadg is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension gfdkimpbcpahaombhbimeihdjnejgicl is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension kmendfapggjehodndflmmgagdbamhnfd is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension mfehgcgbbipciphmccgaenjidiccnmng is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension mgndgikekgjfcpckkfioiadnlibdjbkf is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension neajdppkdcdipfabeoofebfddakdcjhd is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension nkeimhogjdpnpccoofpliimaahmaaome is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(417)] Extension pafkbggdmjlpgkdkcbjmhmfcdpncadgh is not auto updateable
[4024:4788:0130/140352:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(765)] Finished update check 1
```

The update xml file looks like this:

```
<gupdate xmlns="http://www.google.com/update2/response" protocol="2.0">
<app appid="dcpd....">
<updatecheck codebase="https://my-autoupdate-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/extension.crx" version="1.0.11"/>
</app>
</gupdate>
```

The manifest.json in the crx has a valid update_url pointing to the right place.

```
{
  "name": "My Extension Name",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "update_url": "https://my-autoupdate-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/the_update.xml",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "notifications",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "48": "RM_icon-48x48.png",
    "128": "RM_icon-128x128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "stacktrace-min-0.3.js",
        "jquery-1.7.2.min.js",
        "underscore.js",
        "content_script.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "plugins": [
    {
      "path": "npRMAccessor.dll",
      "public": true
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

The company has deployed the extension via GPO, setting beneath `User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Classice Administrative Templates\Google\Google Chrome\Extensions`

- Configure the list of force-installed extensions - set to `dcpd....;https://my-autoupdate-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/auto_update.xml` (but with full extension id and correct URL).
- Configure extension, app, and user script install sources - set to `https://my-autoupdate-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/*`

When users with autoupdate not working OR users with autoupdate working visit `chrome://policy` it shows the two policies ('ExtensionInstallForcelist' and 'ExtensionInstallSources') both set and with the correct same values. No other policies are set and no other extensions are installed by policy.

It's been reported and tested a couple of times that if the customer's IT run `gpupdate /force` on a workstation that's not auto-updating then it will auto-update, although I can't see how that can be true. They've also tried pressing 'Update extensions now' button on `chrome://extensions` and that *has* auto-updated the extension. However, neither of these are things I'd like the company's IT team to have to do.

Is there anything that will cause Google Chrome not to attempt to auto-update my extension as part of extension_updater.cc, or anything else I should look at from a troubleshooting perspective?

Problematic machines are running Chrome latest on Windows 7.

Comment: Is update URL properly set in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I've added an example. I've double-checked that the URL is correct and works.